Is there a fix for the dip in these faces?
I've been working on this model for a while and I've found issues in the vertical center of the highlighted part. When seperated the left and right side of the highlighted part are smoothed over quite well by the shading, but when I join them it creates a vertical band over the center of the part that seemingly falls inward. I was wondering if there were any fixes to smooth the part over and smooth out the band without having to change the coordinate of the vertice at the bottom center of that band. Or if the geometry just simply doesn't allow it. I am fairly new so I understand if there are topology issues to navigate I'm just a little unclear on how to go about that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!




Could you show them before AND after the join?

Yes! This is what the two segments look life before the center edge is placed. I assume that's what you mean by join though if it's in regards to something else I can try to clarify.

What I mean by “join” is whatever you meant by “when I join them,” which I did not understand, hence asking for a before/after. Which picture of the three is before and which is after?

hello have you tried to Merge by Distance, recalculate the normals, check for an inner face? Please share this piece: https://blend-exchange.com/

TheLabCat: To clarify when I mean join them I only mean when I add in the two faces in the center of the highlighted segment. These faces make up the section that I say has the "dip" in it. Also the first photo is how it looks after joined and the 3rd photo is before. I realize I accidently deleted the first photo initially and I do apologize
Moonboots: https://blend-exchange.com/b/WDl8Kn6r that is the link for the part. I have tried recalculating normals and ensured all faces are pointing the same direction. Merge by distance, however, removed some of the veticies I need for structure.

here is what i see, i'm not sure what's bad: https://i.postimg.cc/RFxGRFDS/1.jpg

All I mean to fix is the band across the center of the highlighted part that gives the impression of a dip in the part, though I'm not sure if there is necessarily a fix for that.
